# fullCalendar, dayClick gives wrong time

Tags: fullcalendar

i am using fullCalendar bower: v3.9.* (=latest tag)
when i click on a free slot 11:00
then my function is triggered:

```
dayClick: function (momentDateFromFullcalendar) {
    // workaround, fullcalender gives me wrong time
    var momentDate = null;
    if (moment().isDST()) {
        momentDate = momentDateFromFullcalendar.add(-2, 'h');
    } else {
        momentDate = momentDateFromFullcalendar.add(-1, 'h');
    }

    logger.debug('clicked on date: ' + momentDate.toDate());
    vm.newTermin(momentDate);
}
```

I get from fullcalendar as a param to my callback:

ACTUAL:
13:00 GMT+2

EXPECT: 
11:00 GMT +2

(+2 = +1 CEST and +1 DST)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4uDG.png)

timezone: 'Europe/Vienna',

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Try .toString() instead of .toDate(). I think it's just the presentation which is wrong, rather than the date itself. http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/434/ . Or .toISOString() would work too. See also http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: Please check out the screenshot where I am debugging. I think the param value is already wrong.

Comment: The `_d` field in the screenshot is the same as the output of "toDate()" (i.e. conversion to a native JS Date object). But look at `_i` just below it - the 11 in the hours property is clearly visible, for 11am. Also the `ambigZone: true` indicates that your momentJS object is _ambiguously zoned_. This is a fullCalendar thing, it's a change to momentJS. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment#ambiguously-zoned . Consequently, when working with dates in fullCalendar, stick within momentJS and don't go off into native-date world, as you are doing, because the results are unexpected.

Comment: The parameter value is _not_ already wrong, you're looking at the wrong output from it. Stick with the momentJS functions and you'll get what you expect. In this case, since the moment is in UTC, converting it to local time would indeed increase it by 2 hours, and when it's converted to a native Date, that's what happens. But in fullCalendar's modified momentJS world, the time is expressed in UTC. Setting the timezone, as you've done, is merely to provide instructions to your server as to how to return event data (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone) and that's not relevant to this code.

Comment: In general, unless you absolutely need internationalisation and displaying things in different timezones to different users, it's best to just forget about it.